# I am not going to use my visa; do I need to cancel it?

Tags: us-citizens, schengen-visas

I got a short-stay visa in December for France and I was unable to go/put it to use. It expires at the end of June; however. I will be studying in France from the start of June to the end of July. Will I get kicked out? Will they refuse my entry. I will not need a visa for the summer because I will not be in the country for longer than 3 months. Do I need to get my old visa voided?

Comment: You are unable to cancel a visa and no one really cares, plans change all the time, an unused visa is not a problem. But this question makes no sense. What's your citizenship? If you are visa free for 90 day stays (which is the maximum for any short stay) then why did you get a visa in December?